# Merging my branch to master which is already merged with changes from master

Tags: git, github, git-bash

```
1.              C
                | 
                B-D-E
                |    my branch
                A
                master
```

2. I merged by branch with changes from develop

   ```
            C
            | 
            B-D-C-E
            |    my branch
            A
            master
   ```
3. Now I need to merge my branch to master

Will this duplicate commit **C** in master?

Comment: While you can *copy* some existing commit to a new commit, it's impossible to truly *duplicate* a commit. A commit is a numbered entity. Its number is its hash ID. The number of any given commit is *unique:* that number means *that commit*, and never any other commit. The commits you see in `git log` output are numbered, and those numbers are exactly those commits. *Branches* are irrelevant here: only the *commits* matter.

Comment: When you run `git merge` to merge a branch, you get either a *fast-forward* operation, where the current branch name now selects the *same commit* as the other branch, or you get a new *merge commit*. A merge commit is a commit with two or more parent commits. So your drawing is wrong: it shows two different commits `C`, but there can only be one `C`; either `master` now names commit `E`, or there is a new commit `F` that joins commits `A` and `E` together, and `master` now names new commit `F`.

Answer (score 1):

In git, a branch is just a pointer to a commit - like a tag, but moveable. It is the "parents" of commits that actually make the history. (I've deliberately *not* made all the branches neat lines in the diagrams below to emphasise that.)

From your description, it sounds like your initial state was this (you didn't tell us where "develop" pointed):

```
      /- C <-[develop]
     /
A - B <-[master]
     \
      \- D - E <-[my_branch]
```

If you merged develop into my_branch, the default would be to create a "merge commit", like this:

```
       [develop]
         v
      /- C -----\
     /           \
A - B <-[master]  \
     \             F <-[my_branch]
      \- D - E --/
```

Merging that to master with another merge commit would look like this:

```
       [develop]
         v
      /- C -----\
     /           \
A - B             \
    |\             F <-[my_branch]
    | \- D - E --/  \
    |                \
     \--------------- G <-[master]
```

There's no duplication here. But nor is there ever a state that looks like what you drew in the question.

---

If instead of a normal merge, you *rebased* my_branch onto develop, you would get this (note that commits D2 and E2 are new commits created by the rebase based on D and E):

```
       [develop]
         v
      /- C - D2 - E2 <-[my_branch]
     /
A - B <-[master]
     \
      \- D - E <-[abandoned commits]
```

Then a merge to master would look like this:

```
       [develop]  [my_branch]
         v         v
      /- C - D2 - E2 -\  
     /                 F <-[master]
A - B ----------------/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try a couple of things:

1. Rebase your branch to master - it should get rid of C. Works in simple cases. Tends to be a problem if you merge your branch with master - recommend not to mix merge and rebase. After the rebase you'd need to do a "git push -f" to force overwrite on github, and if anybody else is sharing your branch warn then not to merge with yours but to retake from your latest (another way of getting a mess if you are not careful).
2. (Assuming you are using PRs), squash-merge on completion - at which point only the difference between the two branches matters and the history of that branch will be thrown away.

I personally prefer squash merges for this reason.